# I want to update the network and subnet ids into the template file using shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line-interface

I have tried with sed command to replace the network and subnet values but it is updating same values in all network/subnet lines.

Below is the values need update in template

```
net1="network1"
sub1="subnet1"

net2="network2"
sub2="subnet2"

net3="network3"
sub3="subnet3"

net4="network4"
sub4="subnet4"
```

below is the template file,

```
       vm_group:
        - name: man1
          image: ubuntu18.04
          flavor: ram12
          volume: 500
          ext_net:
            - network: 
              subnet: 
            - network: 
              subnet: 
            - network: 
              subnet: 
            - network: 
              subnet:
                sriov:enabled
        zone: availablity-zone1

      vm_group:
        - name: man2
          image: ubuntu18.04
          flavor: ram12
          volume: 500
          ext_net:
            - network: 
              subnet: 
            - network: 
              subnet: 
            - network: 
              subnet: 
            - network: 
              subnet:
                sriov:enabled
        zone: availablity-zone2
```

below script i tried but it updated net2 and sub2 in all the networks and subnet lines

```
    file_path="path/to/your/file.yaml"

    # Replace network and subnet values for man1 group
    sed -i "s/\(network:\).*/\1 ${net1}\n      subnet: ${sub1}\n    - network: ${net2}\n      subnet: ${sub2}\n    - network: ${net3}\n      subnet: ${sub3}\n    - network: ${net4}\n      subnet: ${sub4}/" ${file_path}

    # Replace network and subnet values for man2 group
    sed -i "s/\(network:\).*/\1 ${net1}\n      subnet: ${sub1}\n    - network: ${net3}\n      subnet: ${sub3}\n    - network: ${net4}\n      subnet: ${sub4}\n    - network: ${net2}\n      subnet: ${sub2}/" ${file_path}
```

expected output:

```
      vm_group:
        - name: man1
          image: ubuntu18.04
          flavor: ram12
          volume: 500
          ext_net:
            - network: net1
              subnet: sub1
            - network: net2
              subnet: sub2
            - network: net3
              subnet: sub3
            - network: net4
              subnet: sub4
                sriov:enabled
        zone: availablity-zone1

      vm_group:
        - name: man2
          image: ubuntu18.04
          flavor: ram12
          volume: 500
          ext_net:
            - network: net3
              subnet: sub3
            - network: net1
              subnet: sub1
            - network: net4
              subnet: sub4
            - network: net2
              subnet: sub2
                sriov:enabled
        zone: availablity-zone2
```

thanks

Comment: This looks like a YAML file, can't you use `yq`? Seems a lot more robust than some sed scripts

Comment: Fix your broken YAML and use Python `yq`

Comment: dont want to use python, need to use shell script

Comment: It's not Python, but a command line written in Python There's also a `go` version, but Python is better

Comment: clearly understood, working on shell script only. please guide me to do in shell script

Comment: can you give me some sample like above

Comment: If do you want to help people please do. thanks

Comment: Why do you consider calling `sed` to be a valid shell script, but calling `yq` to be "not a shell script"? Trying to understand your requirements here

Comment: The script in your question uses GNU `sed` which is neither a bash builtin nor a mandatory POSIX tool but you can install it and call it in a shell script. @GillesQuénot is recommending you use `yq` instead which is also neither a bash builtin nor a mandatory POSIX tool but you can also install it and call it in a shell script. So, we're struggling to understand why you're rejecting `yq` saying you `need to use shell script` but are OK with GNU `sed` - please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements for which tool(s) you can/can't use.

Comment: in the sample code you mention `man2` but in the data all I see are two instances of `man1` ...  ???  do you really want to apply the replacements in a different order (`net3` / `net1` / `net4` / `net2`) for the 2nd group?

Comment: what's the purpose of the initial list of replacements (eg, `net1="network1"`) since a) the `net1` does not show up in the template file and b) `network1` does not show up in the expected output? please update the question to either remove that initial list of replacements or update the template and expected outputs to correspond with this list of replacements

Comment: yes it should have different order for man1 and man2. I have given sample values instead uuids.